# ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder Unable to find a region via the region provider chain

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier, aws-java-sdk

The AWS Glacier API gives me an error about not finding the region even when I specify it specifically:

```
EndpointConfiguration endpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration("https://glacier.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/", "us-east-2");

AmazonGlacier glacierClient = AmazonGlacierClientBuilder.standard()
  .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig)
  .withCredentials(credentials)
  .build();

ArchiveTransferManager xferMgr = new ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder()
    .withGlacierClient(glacierClient)
    .build();

    UploadResult result = xferMgr.upload("Data_Full", "my archive " + (new Date()), new File("C:\\myBigFile"));
```

I get this stack trace:

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder
>   or setup environment to supply a region.  at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:371)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:337)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient(AmazonSQSClientBuilder.java:44)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.glacier.transfer.ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder.resolveSQSClient(ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder.java:129)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.glacier.transfer.ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder.getParams(ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder.java:135)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.glacier.transfer.ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder.build(ArchiveTransferManagerBuilder.java:143)

Note that I use the API to list vaults and it works:

```
AmazonGlacierClientBuilder clientbuilder = AmazonGlacierClientBuilder.standard();
EndpointConfiguration endpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration("https://glacier.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/", "us-east-2");
clientbuilder.withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig);
ProfilesConfigFile cf = new ProfilesConfigFile();
AWSCredentialsProvider credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider(cf, "My AWS Profile Name");
clientbuilder.setCredentials(credentials);
AmazonGlacier glacierClient = CustomAmazonGlacierClientBuilder.buildCustomAmazonGlacierClient();
ListVaultsRequest request = new ListVaultsRequest();
ListVaultsResult result = glacierClient.listVaults(request);
```

I recently downloaded the AWS / Glacier libraries as an Eclipse plugin. It shows the .jar version of aws-java-sdk-opensdk-1.11.130.jar

Does anyone have any insight as to what I could put in the code to satisfy the region requirement?  I'd rather do it programmatically

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding the AWS_REGION environment variable. E.g. us-east-2.  When using Eclipse, you can add this using the Run --> Run Configurations.

I also updated the Eclipse and AWS Eclipse plugins using the Eclipse Help --> Check for Updates feature.